# How can I identify specific string row number

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(Main = structure(c(5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("IsMainbody", "IsMainbodyCandidate", 
"IsMainbodyRejected", "Main", "None"), class = "factor"), Group.IDs = c(52L, 
NA, 2L, 12L, 38L, 38L, 6L, 3L, NA, 49L, 20L, 38L, 54L, 85L), 
    X..Number1 = c(12L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 4L), X..No = c(20L, 62L, 2L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 32L, 3L, 36L, 3L, 1L, 20L), X..Unique.N = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

I am trying to find the row number of for specific strings. 
Based on **main** column, I want to find this how many of my sample has "Main" , how many have "IsmainbodyCandidate" and how many are "IsMainbodyRejected"

Then I want to make a new dataset that only consists of **Main** and **Ismainbody** and **Ismainbodycandidates** like below .

```
Main       Group IDs    # Number1   # No    # Unique N
IsMainbody.     2        1         2           1
IsMainbodyCandidate 12   5        16           0
Main           38        1        3            0
Main           38        1        3             0
IsMainbodyCandidate 6    1        1            0
IsMainbody  3            1        3           0
IsMainbodyCandidate 49   1        3           0
IsMainbodyCandidate 85   4       20            0
```

Comment: `df[df$Main != "None",]` should work...

Comment: Your example data does not contain either "maincandidate" or "Ismainbodycandidates"; can you edit the question so names are consistent.

Comment: @neilfws I corrected it , thanks

Comment: @AntoniosK no it does not, it also take the rejected inside

Comment: Then try this `df[!df$Main %in% c("None","IsMainbodyRejected"),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# count by main
table(df$Main)

# new dataframe without "None"
df[df$Main != "None", ]

# or more explicitly
df[df$Main %in% c("Main", "IsMainbody", "IsMainbodyCandidate"), ]
```